# Ubuntu 13.10, after update login loop

Tags: login, login-screen, auto-login

So, today I update some packages and then I shut it down. When I turn it on, it ask for a pw (I had automatic login).

Tried several things, removing .Xauthority, .cache and .ICEauthority, check rights on /tmp, reconfiguring ubuntu-desktop and lightdm

Nothing

This is my auth.log

```
May  4 19:14:17 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
May  4 19:14:17 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user elect by (uid=0)
May  4 19:14:17 elect-desktop systemd-logind[612]: New session c4 of user elect.
May  4 19:14:17 elect-desktop systemd-logind[612]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/1000/X11-display.
May  4 19:14:18 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user elect
May  4 19:14:19 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
May  4 19:14:19 elect-desktop systemd-logind[612]: Removed session c4.
May  4 19:14:19 elect-desktop systemd-logind[612]: New session c5 of user lightdm.
May  4 19:14:19 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "elect"
May  4 19:14:19 elect-desktop lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "elect"
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me be quick and concise without saying any bad word

The problem was Nvidia, I got a clue from [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1411104)

Reinstalled with some troubles, it complained a mismatched version of gcc (4.6 vs 4.8)..

I tried to push the 4.8 on top, although it looked already so but unsuccessfully…

So I removed completely any trace of 4.6, still problems

Then I removed every gcc, and got the 4.8 back by reinstalling the build-essential, that took care also about some configurations, as I hoped

Rebooted, It worked out